# Export to PDF with parameters

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation, export-to-pdf

Been reading about how to save sheet to a PDF file and I stumble to this code it works well before but now it won't been getting error of "uiapp deprecated". How can I fix this? BTW the codes not mine,I just tweak it to suit my preferences. It's suggesting to use HTML Services.

```
function PDF() {
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var gid = sheet.getSheetId();
    var pdfOpts = '&size=letter&fzr=false&portrait=true&fitw=false&gridlines=false&scale=1&top_margin=0.17&bottom_margin=0.17&left_margin=0.1&right_margin=0.1&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&attachment=false&gid='+gid;
    var row2 = 66;
    var printRange = '&c1=0' + '&r1=0' + '&c2=15' + '&r2='+row2; // B2:APn
    var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '') + 'export?format=pdf' + pdfOpts + printRange;
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(300).setHeight(100);
    app.setTitle('Print this sheet');
    var link = app.createAnchor('Download PDF', url).setTarget('_new');
    app.add(link);
    ss.show(app);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification? I think that there might be several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, I used the method of showModalDialog of Class Ui.

From:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(300).setHeight(100);
app.setTitle('Print this sheet');
var link = app.createAnchor('Download PDF', url).setTarget('_new');
app.add(link);
ss.show(app);
```

To:

```
var html = '<a href="' + url.replace(/&/g, "&amp;") + '" target="_new">Download PDF</a>';
var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(300).setHeight(100);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Print this sheet');
```

#### Reference:

- [Class Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)

If I misunderstood your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: @Jayson Roque Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.