# google sheets UiApi to htmlservice script file upload

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got the problem since google isnt supporting UIapi anymore i cant use the code below. Could someone help me with it and re-edit to html service? I have no clue about any of those stuff. Code was copied from other site long time ago. Tryed to find a solution for the last 2 days and nothing. Would be really greatfull.
regards

// upload document into google spreadsheet
    // and put link to it into current cell

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "", functionName: "doGet"});
  ss.addMenu("", menuEntries);
}

function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
  var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
  form.add(formContent);  
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));

  // these parameters need to be passed by form
  // in doPost() these cannot be found out anymore
  formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeCell", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()));
  formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeSheet", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()));
  formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeSpreadsheet", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()));
  formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton(''));
  app.add(form);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
  return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.createLabel('');
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
  var doc = DriveApp.getFolderById('0BzI2pkyLXZ5maWo5b2Uyb3JWdzQ').createFile(fileBlob);
  var label = app.createLabel('');

  // write value into current cell
  var value = 'hyperlink("' + doc.getUrl() + '";"' + doc.getName() + '")'
  var activeSpreadsheet = e.parameter.activeSpreadsheet;
  var activeSheet = e.parameter.activeSheet;
  var activeCell = e.parameter.activeCell;
  var label = app.createLabel('');
  app.add(label);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(activeSpreadsheet).getSheetByName(activeSheet).getRange(activeCell).setFormula(value);
  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54375744/7108653

Comment: Not really but thanks for the effort. What do i need is a code which uploads a file to a current cell i google sheets from my hdd and saves it on my google drive. Something like a hiperlink.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.